How to install Swift?
I have to install Swift.
OS is Linux Mint Cinnamon (i.e. v20 or so)
After tearing my hair out about tarballs etc. from the swift.org site, I finally found this answer here.
The first command seems to have worked...
sudo apt install ubuntu-make

but the second not so much:
mike@M17A:~$ umake swift
usage: umake [--help] [-v] [-r] [-l | --list-installed | --list-available] [--version]
             {android,dart,electronics,games,go,ide,kotlin,maven,nodejs,rust,scala,web} ...
umake: error: argument category: invalid choice: 'swift' (choose from 'android', 'dart', 'electronics', 'games', 'go', 'ide', 'kotlin', 'maven', 'nodejs', 'rust', 'scala', 'web')

Anyone know what I have to do?

removed the [tag:gnu-make] tag from this, because it has nothing to do with it :) I'm amazed by the existence of Ubuntu make, which, to let it describe itself: "…is a command line tool which allows you to download the latest version of popular developer tools on your installation, installing it alongside all of the required dependencies (which will only ask for root access if you don't have all the required dependencies installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if you are on a 64 bit machine,[…] Basically, one command to get your system ready to develop with!"

Dear Canonical, you're re-inventig apt-get. Apt-get does that. Speak to the people that build your distro. They are already using apt-get. You can have multiple repositories in apt-get. You don't have to re-invent apt-get.

What is swift? Where would one find it? Have you checked what instructions its developers give for installing?

@terdon Swift is a relatively important programming language (see the tag!), its main developers are apple, so their Linux instructions are lacking.

@MarcusMüller they are? https://www.swift.org/install/linux/tarball/ seems quite detailed.

@terdon fair enough.

@terdon as I say, I was tearing my hair out because, for example, there is no "swift" executable under the directory extracted from the (static) tarball. I'm a low-level Linux user and multiple confusing things happened when I tried to go down the tarball-extraction route. Have found another tarball possibility (https://ultahost.com/knowledge-base/install-swift-on-ubuntu/) and am actively trying that ...

No need to delete! If you show us what you tried and how it failed we might be able to help, but we need to know what you did first. The instructions seem long, but detailed.

@terdon Thanks for getting back to me... that page I linked to in the previous post did the trick, and can serve as a template for me for installing from tarballs in the future, with a bit of luck. I deleted because handling a tarball is probably pretty basic stuff for most Linuxers!

Ah OK, if you are no longer looking for the answer then we can close. To be honest, the page seems like it is mostly saying the same things as https://www.swift.org/install/linux/tarball/ but if you find it easier to follow, fair enough. If you could post the steps that worked for you as an answer, that really would be the best!

The explanations for installation at swift.org didn't work for me: baffling,  incomprehensible errors.
But I found an answer which worked for me here. Hopefully this a good general recipe for installations from a downloaded tarball.
However, step 2, "install required dependencies" is a bit mysterious:
sudo apt install clang libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev

... there's no particular explanation where that comes from. The dependencies for Ubuntu 20.04 at swift.org are completely different.
